# Сравнение объектов и сокращенные варианты

Tags: java

На уроке показали вот такой пример специально опустили private и геттеры и сеттеры:

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    String brand;
    String model;
    int year;

    public Car(String brand, String model, int year) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }

 @Override
    public int compareTo(Car car) {
        if (this.year == car.year) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.year < car.year) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Могу ли я заменить вот этот кусок кода:

```
 @Override
        public int compareTo(Car car) {
            if (this.year == car.year) {
                return 0;
            } else if (this.year < car.year) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
```

На этот:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Car car) {
        return Integer.compare(this.year, car.year);
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста будет ли это правильным или нет?

И еще вопрос по этой же теме:

Вот дополнение кода и сортирует правильно по ГОДУ (year), но как сделать чтобы сортировало по всем полям?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Car> myCarList = new TreeSet<>();
        Car firstCar = new Car("Mercedes", "E200", 2015);
        Car secondCar = new Car("Bmw", "M5", 2017);
        Car thirdCar = new Car("Audi", "Q8", 2020);

        myCarList.add(firstCar);
        myCarList.add(secondCar);
        myCarList.add(thirdCar);

        for (Car car: myCarList) {
            System.out.println(car);
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы сортировало по всем полям я сделал вот так:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Car car) {
        if (this.brand.equals(car.brand) && this.model.equals(car.model) && this.year == car.year) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.brand.equals(car.brand) &&  this.model.equals(car.model) && this.year < car.year) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Но сортирует только по году (year), подскажите пожалуйста как сделать в моем примере сортировку по всем полям?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вариант абсолютно правильный, так и нужно делать

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Car car) {
    return Integer.compare(this.year, car.year);
}
```

Что касается сортировки по нескольким полям, то для этого есть несколько вариантов:

*Первый вариант:*

Сравнивать каждое поле поэтапно

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Car car) {
    int result;
    result = brand.compareTo(car.getBrand());
    if(result != 0) return result;
    result = model.compareTo(car.getModel());
    if(result != 0) return result;
    result = Integer.compare(year, car.getYear());
    return result;
}
```

---

*Второй вариант:*

Использовать компаратор. В этом случае в классе нужно создать приватное поле с компаратором, а в методе `compareTo` вызывать этот компаратор

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private final Comparator<Car> comparator = Comparator
            .comparing(Car::getBrand)
            .thenComparing(Car::getModel)
            .thenComparingInt(Car::getYear);

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car car) {
        return comparator.compare(this, car);
    }
    
    // getters, setters, etc...
}
```

---

*Третий вариант:*

Использовать стороннюю библиотеку. Например, вот так это можно сделать с помощью Google Guava

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Car car) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(brand, car.getBrand())
            .compare(model, car.getModel())
            .compare(year, car.getYear())
            .result();
}
```

Comment: А вот первый вариант я добавил и он отсортировал только ничего не отсортировано

Comment: @MikeMclaren строки сортируются не по длине, а в алфавитном порядке. Вам как именно нужно их сравнить?

Comment: Car{brand=Audi, model=Q8, year='2020'}
Car{brand=Bmw, model=M5, year='2017'}
Car{brand=Mercedes, model=E200, year='2015'}

Comment: Вот как отсортировало с вашим первом вариантом, получается brand нормально отработал, а model и year - нет

Comment: @MikeMclaren вы похоже не совсем понимаете, как работает сортировка. Поля сортируются по порядку и только если какие-то поля равны, то в этом случае происходит сортировка по следующему полю и так далее. То есть в вашем случае сортировка всегда будет только по полю Brand (потому что оно первое в методе сортировки). Но если бы у вас было, допустим, два объекта с brand = "Bmw", то в этом случае они бы уже сортировались по полю model

Comment: Спасибо, я понял как работает сортировка. А нельзя с помощью compareTo() добится сортировки по всем полям сразу. А то в данный момент сортирует только по бренду (если брать первый вариант показанный вами). Еще хотел спросить почему Audi стоит выше чем Bmw, если в bmw 3 буквы, а у Audi 4, получается Bmw должен быть первым как я понял